# Animate button move and set new position in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I've an ImageButton that I want to move when pressed and when animation finish I want that this button stops in the new position.

This is button code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/move_button"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/background_button"
    android:src="@drawable/move_button"
    android:onClick="MoveButton" />
```

I've found a code to do that in this site:

```
public void MoveButton(final View view) {    
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100, 0);
        anim.setDuration(300);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
                params.topMargin += -100;
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });

        view.startAnimation(anim);

    }
```

When button it's pressed it start the animation, but when animation is complete button return to initial position and application crashes.

What can be the problem?

Comment: because you are setting param to view so it will change back to initial position after 300ms after animation ends so set ImageButton params at end

Answer (score 5):

This is work Definitely.

```
Button im= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
//set position TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta
final Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,100,0,0);
// set Animation for 5 sec
animation.setDuration(5000);
//for button stops in the new position.
animation.setFillAfter(true);
im.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: It didnot work for me. Button gets hidden for given time

Comment: @Shubham you need to change values for new TranslateAnimation(0,100,0,0); as per your requiremntes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `anim.setFillAfter(true)` to situated the `View` at the position where **Animation** ends.

One thing more you are animating your `ImageButton` from 100 to 0 in Y coordinates, thats why your `ImageButton` comes to intial position because 0 is its intial position.

Try below code in this code I used `anim.setFillAfter(true)` and **animate** the `ImageButton` from 0 to 100 in Y coordinates.

```
public void MoveButton(final View view) {
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,100);
        anim.setDuration(300);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

     view.startAnimation(anim);

 }
```

Let me know if this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObjectAnimator`

```
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(YOUR_VIEW, "translationX", 100f);
        animation.setDuration(2000);
        animation.start();
```

This code will move the `View` 100 pixles to the right, over a period of 2 seconds.

If you need more information go to [Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view#java)

Answer (score 0):

Import the necessary libraries:

```
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
```

Get the button you need to use:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
```

Now in order to animate `button` you will need to use the `TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, toXDelta, fromYDelta, toYDelta)` function which takes **4 float** arguments.

Animation Example:

```
Animation your_animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,100,0,0);
```

The first argument specifies the start of the **x position** and the second one the end of the **x position**, Same thing for  the other two but the **y position** instead.

You will also need to set your animation's duration in milliseconds using

```
your_animation.setDuration(1000);
```

Your button will get back to its previous position when the animation ends, in order to make the button stay to its new position, use this:

```
your_animation.setFillAfter(true)
```

For more information on animations https://developer.android.com/training/animation